# No se guarda la ruta completa en el media cuando implemento django-tenants en mi proyecto de django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, multitenant

Estoy implementando multitenant en un proyecto de django con PostgreSQL para ello implemente una librería llamada **django-tenants** pero tengo un pequeño problema lo que deseaba era guardar por cada esquema los archivo media en un folder con el mismo nombre del esquema para ello en la documentación oficial me indicaba que tenia que poner en mi settings.py esta configuración.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_tenants.files.storage.TenantFileSystemStorage'

MULTITENANT_RELATIVE_MEDIA_ROOT = ""
```

Tengo un modelo de ejemplo

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Nombre')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Imagen')
```

Pero cuando guardo un registro efectivamente se crea en el media un folder con el nombre del esquema actual junto con la imagen pero en mi base de datos se guarda la imagen sin el nombre del esquema es decir.

```
Se guarda /product/2023/08/30/imagen.png

En vez de esquema1/product/2023/08/30/imagen.png
```

¿Como podria solucionar esto? he buscado diferentes soluciones pero no he podido encontrar la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno después de varios días buscando una solución pude hacerlo de la siguiente forma.

```
from django.db import models, connection

def image_upload_path(base_path):
    def upload_path(instance, filename):
       current_date = datetime.now()
       return f {connection.schema_name}/{base_path}/{current_date.year}/{current_date.month}/{current_date.day}/{filename}"

    return upload_path

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Nombre')
    image = models.ImageField(image_upload_path('product'), null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Imagen')
```

Con esto logre que se coloque en la ruta el nombre del esquema actual, pero bueno pensándolo bien si hacia un rename del esquema talvez esto no seria muy útil así que lo deje como viene por defecto el guardado de la ruta y mejor cree un método para poder llamar a la ruta de la imagen con el esquema actual así me funcionaria mejor si llega a pasar esto.

```
    def get_image(self):
        if self.image:
           return f'{settings.MEDIA_URL}{connection.schema_name}/{self.image}'
        return f'{settings.STATIC_URL}img/default/empty.png'
```